# Visual C++ compile all x64 builds command line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, command-line, build, command

Is it possible to make all x64 builds to compile using a one line only command? Currently I have to type one by one as follows:

```
devenv.com MyDir\MySolution.sln /Build "Debug|x64"
devenv.com MyDir\MySolution.sln /Build "Release|x64"
devenv.com MyDir\MySolution.sln /Build "DebugUnicode|x64"
devenv.com MyDir\MySolution.sln /Build "ReleaseUnicode|x64"
etc.
```

and wait for each one to complete to pass to the next.

Comment: Create a .bat file containing those commands. Then issue a "one line only command" that executes this .bat file.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: that is not a solution.

Comment: It seems to satisfy your stated requirements. In what respect do you find it lacking?

Comment: I don't want to create a lot of bat files, for each solution I have. And the source code tree is gigantic.

Comment: Create one batch file that can take solution as a parameter.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Not all files have the same structure of configurations. There are a lot of 3rd Partys where the configuration names differ, even from each other!